# Get QKeySequenceEdit value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Am having issues getting the value of my "QKeySequenceEdit", I need to get this value to print it on a label and console.

This is my code:

```
  ##Create my KeySecuenceEdit
        self.ksec_hotkey = QtWidgets.QKeySequenceEdit(self.gpb_main)##it is inside of a groupbox
        self.ksec_hotkey.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 75, 85, 27))
        self.ksec_hotkey.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.ksec_hotkey.setObjectName("ksec_hotkey")
        self.ksec_hotkey.keySequenceChanged.connect(self.show_ksec)##Call my function here

    ##function to get and print keySequenceEdit value
    def show_ksec(self):    
        ksec_value = self.ksec_hotkey.keySequence()
        #print(str(ksec_value))   ##does not work
        #print(ksec_value.__dict__)   ##.__dict__  or .__repr__ does not work
        print(ksec_value)   ##prints "<PyQt5.QtGui.QKeySequence object at 0x7f28386a5dd0>"
        self.lbl_print_hotkey.setText(" : " + str(ksec_value))   ##prints "<PyQt5.QtGui.QKeySequence object at 0x7f28386a5dd0>"
```

My code prints: "<PyQt5.QtGui.QKeySequence object at 0x7f28386a5dd0>".

I read about issues with classes, so this is my program so far:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    ##here is my function to print
    def show_ksec(self):


    ##here is where my qkeysequence and all my widgets are
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
```

Comment: Please dont edit pyuic files, it's considered bad practice and almost always leads to unnecessary problems. Follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`toString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#toString) method of `QKeySequence`:

```python
keysequence = self.ksec_hotkey.keySequence()
text = keysequence.toString(QKeySequence.NativeText)
# or
# text = keysequence.toString(QKeySequence.PortableText)
self.lbl_print_hotkey.setText(f" : {text}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but am getting this error now: name 'QKeySequence' is not defined
NameError: name 'keySequence' is not defined

I tried with "'QKeySequence and 'keySequence".

Comment: @devxen21 Use `from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence`

Comment: Thans @eyllanesc, I had only this "from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets" but adding "from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence" works great!